# Terminology : What is C#, C#.Net and C#.Net Framework?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I'm a bit of a newbie in C# still, and I was wondering what elements pertain uniquely to C# and what elements are unique to the .Net Framework.

Are the keywords, operators, compiler, compiler errors and preprocessor directives the only members of C# itself? Does C# have any other members, or are some of the previous members attributed to the .Net Framwork?

In addition, in a Console Application, are the following namespaces used to contain .Net Framework members?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Are the keywords, operators, compiler, compiler errors and preprocessor directives the only members of C# itself?

Basically.  The language you type, and the syntax you use, is specific to C# and the C# language and compilers.  This means the keywords and operators are specific to the language (C#), though they often use types provided by the framework.

> In addition, in a Console Application, do the following namespaces used to contain .Net Framework members?

Yes, those are all namespaces with types that exist in the .NET Framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest rule to tell what is unique to C# and what is generally available on .NET Framework, is to go to the specifications of C# and CIL,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa569283.aspx

C# language is finally compiled to CIL, so generally speaking except the language sugars which are lost after compilation, the basic building blocks are exactly the same. Note that CIL does have something that C# does not have, which can be found from the specs, but since they are rarely significant, I could hardly recall what they are at this moment.